# Debian 9 udev keyboard rule not working

Tags: linux, usb, debian, keyboard, udev

Every time I lock my screen / remove my keyboard and re-plug it in (usb) the keyboard repeat rate resets. I am trying to fix this by creating a udev rule.

I have created a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d` called `21_persistent-local.rules` it contains:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2106", RUN+="/home/user/keyboard-connect-test-script.sh"
```

`keyboard-connect-test-script.sh` contains:

```
echo "keyboard connected" >> /home/user/keyboard.log
```

I have applied `chmod +x` to this script, and the file `keyboard.log` exists.

I have run `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and there are no obvious errors in `udevadm test --action=add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:413C:2106.001C/input/input40` which produces:

```
calling: test
version 235
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          235
file size:         9212225 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1931297 bytes
nodes              7280848 bytes
Load module index
Failed to read $container of PID 1, ignoring: Permission denied
Found container virtualization none.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/80-container-ve.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .link.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/80-container-vz.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .link.
Ignoring /lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network, because it's not a regular file with suffix .link.
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/21_persistent-local.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/39-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-hpmud.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-crda.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-fuse.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-sensor.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-debian-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-joystick.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-cinterion-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-dell-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-haier-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-mtk-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-pcmcia-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-platform-serial-whitelist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qdl-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-telit-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-serial-adapters-greylist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-debian-compat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-ifupdown.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-libinput-device-groups.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/84-nm-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-nm-unmanaged.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-console-setup.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-libgpod.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-libinput-model-quirks.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-dm-notify.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 36236 bytes strings
28450 strings (232117 bytes), 24709 de-duplicated (199623 bytes), 3742 trie nodes used
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:14
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' returned non-zero
IMPORT builtin 'input_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules:5
capabilities/ev raw kernel attribute: 120013
capabilities/abs raw kernel attribute: 0
capabilities/rel raw kernel attribute: 0
capabilities/key raw kernel attribute: 1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
properties raw kernel attribute: 0
test_key: checking bit block 0 for any keys; found=1
test_key: checking bit block 64 for any keys; found=1
test_key: checking bit block 128 for any keys; found=1
test_key: checking bit block 192 for any keys; found=1
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:11
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0: if_class 3 protocol 0
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:35
RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
.INPUT_CLASS=kbd
.MM_USBIFNUM=00
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:413C:2106.001E/input/input42
EV=120013
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_4_1_0
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=Dell_QuietKey_Keyboard
ID_MODEL_ENC=Dell\x20QuietKey\x20Keyboard
ID_MODEL_ID=2106
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_4_1_0
ID_REVISION=0101
ID_SERIAL=DELL_Dell_QuietKey_Keyboard
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=DELL
ID_VENDOR_ENC=DELL
ID_VENDOR_ID=413c
KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v413Cp2106e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8C,8E,96,98,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,AD,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="DELL Dell QuietKey Keyboard"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0"
PRODUCT=3/413c/2106/110
PROP=0
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=422868148985
run: 'kmod load input:b0003v413Cp2106e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8C,8E,96,98,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,AD,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

I obtained the `idVendor` and `idProduct` codes from `lsusb -v`, the relevant section of which is:

```
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x413c Dell Computer Corp.
  idProduct          0x2106 Dell QuietKey Keyboard
  bcdDevice            1.01
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
```

However I have unplugged and re-plugged the keyboard several times and the `keyboard.log` file is still blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the bash script was missing the shebang.

`keyboard-connect-test-script.sh` Changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "keyboard connected" >> /home/user/keyboard.log
```

It now works, but repeats `keyboard connected` twice for each unplug/plug event. Why?

Comment: It's good you answered your own question. But this last "why?" should be a separate question. Alternatively (as long as there are no other answers addressing your original question) you can delete this answer and rephrase (edit) the question, so it will ask "why twice?" without mentioning the original issue.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It is actually irrelevant but would be nice to know.

Comment: Probably there are two kernel events that match your criteria. Use `udevadm monitor --udev --property` to see which events you get when plugging in the keyboard.